# what can cause id generator in firebird to go wild?

Tags: sql, firebird

I had recently strange problem with firebird database, the id generated for ID i one table went wild
and all of the sudden from 20k jumped to 60k for new inserts. Even more interestingly after
this "jump" following records were getting ID not consecutive number e.g. 60123 and next 60126 if you know what I mean.  Question is what could cause such behavior?

Comment: I don't this question is right for this forum.

Comment: Generators are incremented outside transactions. So, even if you have transaction rolled back, or connection lost, or application hung generator will stay incremented. Just check your code for such situations.

Comment: Sounds as if many inserts are getting rolled back